# GLAD vs GLEW with GLFW

Tags: opengl, glfw, glew, glad

What is the difference between GLAD and GLEW and which one would be better for me to learn?

GLAD appears to be more common. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Read this for the why: [Load OpenGL Functions](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions) and this for what's out there: [OpenGL Loading Library](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library)